# Code "The terminal process failed to launch" Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, archlinux, node-pty

Had this error on Code (1.76.1) when trying to open the integrated terminal.

> The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (/usr/lib/code/node_modules.asar.unpacked/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v88internal20CanHaveInternalFieldEi).

I'm on Arch Linux (6.2.6-arch1-1).

Code worked fine until I did a system update this morning. I also tried to install joplin from the AUR which failed (don't know if it could be related). After that this error came up.

Tried to fully reinstall code but nothing changed

```
[7482:0315/111242.968069:INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "%c[IPC Library: Pty Host] %cError: /usr/lib/code/node_modules.asar.unpacked/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v88internal20CanHaveInternalFieldEi
at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:18)
at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2049)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
at p (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:699)
at bindings (/usr/lib/code/node_modules.asar/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/code/node_modules.asar/spdlog/index.js:3:35)
at u._compile (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:1313)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at r (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:101)
at e.load (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:1720)
at e.load (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:3:10382)
at a (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:10224)
at Object.errorback (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:10345)
at e.triggerErrorback (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:3:10746)
at /usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:3:10452
at e.load (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:1737)
at e.load (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:3:10382)
at a (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:10224)
at s._loadModule (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:10354)
at s._resolve (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:452)
at s.defineModule (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:6066)
at s._relativeRequire (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:6752)
at r (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:9330)
at A.l (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:22826)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at A (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:22806)
at D.n (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:23936)
at new D (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:23806)
at A.k (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:24502)
at A.createLogger (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:20:16533)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.js:27:14663)
at s._safeInvokeFunction (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1337)
at s._invokeFactory (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1522)
at s.complete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1801)
at s._onModuleComplete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:1112)
at s._onModuleComplete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:1358)
at s._resolve (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:510)
at s.defineModule (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:6066)
at n (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:10527)
at Object.R (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:6036)
at s._safeInvokeFunction (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1337)
at s._invokeFactory (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1522)
at s.complete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:1801)
at s._onModuleComplete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:1112)
at s._onModuleComplete (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:1358)
at s._resolve (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:510)
at s.defineModule (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:5:6066)
at y (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:6:1825)
at h (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:2554)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/platform/terminal/node/ptyHostMain.nls.js:3:61)
at e._createAndEvalScript (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:2598)
at /usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:2237
at p (/usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:4190)
at /usr/lib/code/out/vs/loader.js:4:4263
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) color: blue color: ", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/usr/lib/code/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js (21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue tied to glibc have been recorded previously, however, I can see no glibc errors in your trace:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106785

My trace has shown no glibc errors either but updating it helped.
Also recommend updating your electron packages if you have not already.

```
sudo pacman -Syy
sudo pacman -S glibc electron
```

Then restart your VSCode. Fixed the issue for me, hope this helps!

Edit: formatting.